# Automate funding of an account

Tags: contract-development, private-blockchain

I have set automated registration smart contract to register nodes as they are added to a private network. The contract works, however I have run into a problem. When the nodes are set up they have no ether, therefore they cannot send a transaction to the smart contract.

I would like to either:

1) automatically send ether to the nodes when they appear as admin.peers on a master node 
or 
2) set up a “bank” smart contact which I could fill with ether, which would allow the nodes to request a small amount of ether so they could subsequently send a transaction to the registration smart contract.

Is either approach feasible?

Cheers,
P

Answer (score 1):

I think you're conflating "nodes" with "accounts".

> When the nodes are set up they have no ether

Specifically, they have no *accounts*, which have no ether. A node in the network may or may not also host one or more accounts. By default, when you first run a node (e.g. Geth, Parity, etc.) it's just the client software - you have to explicitly create the accounts.

One option in a private network, if you know how many nodes and accounts your network will ultimately have, you could preassign the account addresses and their associated balances via the `genesis.json` file.

- [Preallocate ether using genesis](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10239/preallocate-ether-using-genesis)
- [How to add more Ether on a private blockchain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7578/how-to-add-more-ether-on-a-private-blockchain)

> 1) automatically send ether to the nodes when they appear as
>   admin.peers on a master node

You'd need a way to discover the addresses of the *accounts* on the node. Allowing one node to see which accounts were available on another node would be a security hole.

> 2) set up a “bank” smart contact which I could fill with ether, which
>   would allow the nodes to request a small amount of ether so they could
>   subsequently send a transaction

Chicken/egg problem. You'd need some initial balance to cover the gas cost of calling the `bank` contract.

Comment: Hi Richard,

Thanks for the reply. Apologies, I should have been more specific, when the nodes are set up, I also set up an account (which acts as eth.coinbase for the node), but yes the account has no ether.

Unfortunately pre-allocating is not an option as the nodes (and the associated accounts) will be not be known during the creation of the private blockchain, and I can also now see how option 2 would not be possible.

I have just come across the idea of an ether faucet, so I may look into that as it seems like it may be a possible solution.